# Mapping servlet in root

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, guice, resteasy

What is the right configuration for both of this to "co-exist":

```
http://localhost:8888/index.html

http://localhost:8888/{some_path_value}
```

The first item will be returning a html page and will also containt href that will access resource like `/public/images/bg.png` etc.

Now the second item is a Restful api that is mapped in the same root context ad the one that serves pages (index.html, png, jpg, css, js etc)

So the problem I am facing right now is that when I configure the Rest API servlet mapping like this:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The Rest API works but it effectively removes access to the static resources like index.html, css, js etc. to render a "home page".

However if I changed the mapping to something like `/api/*` the GWT app can now be accessed but the PATH of the Rest API is not the root anymore.

So what could be wrong in my app? I really need to make both co-exist on the same path. My initial idea is to do some kind of filter, but there may be easier and more appropriate solution.

**Update:**

My app's guice **module**:

```
public class MyModule implements Module
{
   public void configure(final Binder binder)
   {
      binder.bind(MyResource.class);
   }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.server.MyModule</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>  
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>  
    <param-value>/api</param-value>  
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your problem is that you are mapping all root requests to go to the rest servlet because it doesnt work otherwise.

1. If there were a way to know some patterns for your rest servlet, you could configure all those specific patterns in your web.xml. But `url-pattern` uses an extremely simple syntax only `whatever/*` and `*.extension` are allowed, and it seems that your rest-servlet does not match this requirement.
2. Another option could be to use an advanced servlet dispatcher like the `GuiceServletContextListener` (provided by [guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule)) and configure a `WebModule` witch rich regular expressions. Modify your `web.xml` to add a `WebModule` and configure that module to handle urls and dispatch with the appropriate servlet (remove these servlets from your web.xml)

```xml
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.guice.modules&lt;/param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.server.MyModule</param-value>
    <param-value>org.jboss.errai.ui.demo.server.MyWebModule</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

```java
  public class MyWebModule extends ServletModule {
    @Override
    protected void configureServlets() {
      // Note: all servlets and filters must be singletons
      bind(FactoryServlet.class).in(Singleton.class);
      // Pass to the HttpServletDispatcher everything but urls ending with static extensions
      serveRegex(".+(?<!\\.(html|css|png|jpg))")
           .with(HttpServletDispatcher.class);
    }
  }
```

1. The last option, is to write your own filter, where you detect whether the path matches a static file and dispatch it.

```java
  private FilterConfig config;
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    config = filterConfig;
  }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,
      ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    File file = new File(config.getServletContext().getRealPath(req.getServletPath()));
    if (file.canRead()) {
      // NOTE: you have to set the most appropriate type per file
      resp.setContentType("text/html");

      // This depends on apache commons-io
      IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(file), resp.getOutputStream());
    } else {
      filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Manolo for this idea, I'm actually using Guice, maybe I can try it

Comment: Sure, If you have problems with reg-exp I could give a hand.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question with the Guice config I have so far

Comment: I'm already using Guice module with my Resteasy resource, what configuration do I need to add?

Comment: What is the TwWebModule the Rest module?

Comment: Changed to MyWebModule, it is the second one in the web.xml

Comment: In my case MyModule is the one that binds the MyResource (Rest resource) in my project; so the MyWebModule would be the one handling request to html, and other static resource right?

Comment: MyWebModule is used to map urls with servlets, so you have to map urls matching your rest requests (ie: /my_entity_001) to the restay servlet. Files not matching those patterns (/index.html) would be passed to your webserver normally (static content).

Comment: Ok i see, I'm just confused whether my exisiting MyModule would interfere with this MyWebModule, since from the web.xml it it mapped in the root.

Comment: Also, should I be doing like: serveRegex("/(images|css|html)/.*").with(HttpServletDispatcher.class); // i mean, i got confused when you added this: serveRegex("/foo_rest_prefix.*", "/bar_rest_prefix.*") where it seems you are accessing a Rest resource when I already have a MyModule which binds the Restful Resource class I have... ?

Comment: another would what is the FactoryServlet for? Isn't serveRegex("/(images|css|html)/.*").with(HttpServletDispatcher.class);  enough to handle static file for example, and let the MyModule work for the Restful access? Please advise.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27726/discussion-between-xybrek-and-manolo)